# Location of DMN FEEL Grammar

Tags: drools, camunda, dmn, feel-language, decision-model-notation

I am looking for formal DMN FEEL grammar (g4 file) to generate ANTLR4 based parser out of it. I am not able to find the grammar file.

Can you please provide where it can be found?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/main/kie-dmn/kie-dmn-feel/src/main/antlr4/org/kie/dmn/feel/parser/feel11/FEEL_1_1.g4

For future reference I found it like this:

1. Googled "github drools" to find the official repository.
2. Searched for a file named "g4".

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't contain functions like FLATTEN, CONCATENATE, REVERSE....Refer: https://kiegroup.github.io/dmn-feel-handbook/#dmn-feel-handbook. So, I was wondering, if it is correct file

Comment: It's the only file.

Comment: Can you point me from where they provide the functions to this grammar file?